# Zooming functionality in d3 - running slowly

Tags: javascript, d3.js, zooming

So, I have a work-able d3 map but the only problem is the zoom is incredibly slow.  This is a map of about 200 points on the globe where I'd like to be able to zoom in/pan and retreive info on each point.  I think d3 looks so much better than leaflet, but for quick zooming/panning functionality, my first question is: is this better off in leaflet or can d3 handle slick zoom/pan even though it's not tile-based?

I've included a snippet of my code below: am I doing something wrong here?  It works as is, but is there a way to make the zoom run more quickly?  Thanks in advance!  Everyone here has been so helpful.

```
function zoomed() {
    console.log("zooming now!")
    ///called on zoom events
d3.selectAll(".centroid").attr("transform", "translate(" +       d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
d3.selectAll(".gratLines").attr("transform", "translate(" +  d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
d3.selectAll(".countries").attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
d3.selectAll(".gratBackground").attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");

};

function setMap() {

var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .translate([0, 0])
    .scale(1)
    .scaleExtent([1, 21])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

console.log("setting map")
var map = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", mapWidth)
    .attr("height", mapHeight)
    .attr("class", "map")

var pageTitle = d3.select("body")
    .append("text")
    .attr("class", "pageTitle")
    .html("UW Hospital Graduates:<br>Where Do They Go?");

var projection = d3.geo.naturalEarth()
    .scale(410)
    .translate([mapWidth / 2, mapHeight / 2])
    .precision(.1);

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);


var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection)
    .pointRadius(3);

//create graticule generator
var graticule = d3.geo.graticule(); 

//create graticule background (aka water)
var gratBackground = map.append("path")
    .datum(graticule.outline)
    .attr("class", "gratBackground")
    .attr("d", path)
    zoom.on('zoom', zoomed)
    map.call(zoom);

var gratLines = map.selectAll(".gratLines")
    .data(graticule.lines) //
    .enter()
    .append("path") //append one path for each element of the data (in this case, each graticule line)
    .attr("class", "gratLines")
    .attr("d", path) //this path is the variable path defined above. path generator
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with d3.js but is it really correct in this library to use `.attr` for *everything* from classes to styles? Being attached to jQuery where attributes are only related to HTML attributes (and should even be distinguished from properties (boolean attributes)) it is odd to see `.attr()` used in this fashion.